# Kotlin - staticProperties and staticFunctions Does Not Include @JvmStatic Annotated Members

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following example

```kotlin
data class Foo(val value: Int) {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val bar = "bar"

        @JvmStatic
        fun baz() = Unit
    }
}
```

I want to obtain the static members of the `Foo` class...

```kotlin
Foo::class.staticProperties // []
Foo::class.staticFunctions // []
```

Why are the resulting collections empty, when the property and function have been annotated `@JvmStatic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `staticProperties` and `staticFunctions` only work for Java classes.
The `staticProperties` documentation says:

> Returns static properties declared in this class. Only properties representing static fields of Java classes are considered static.

Another issue in your case is that you're using `Foo::class` when you should be using `Foo.Companion::class`. They are not the same, accessing companion members using the class name is only syntactic sugar.

I found the following to work for your case:

```
val staticProperties = Foo.Companion::class::memberProperties.get().filter { it.hasAnnotation<JvmStatic>() }
val staticFunctions = Foo.Companion::class::functions.get().filter { it.hasAnnotation<JvmStatic>() }
```